# MonoDroid async service request

Tags: xamarin.android, wcf-client

- I think my issue is somehow related to the issue described in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526125/monodroid-wcf-request-response-of-2-asynch-requests-got-mixed. If it is so, the question is when it's going to be fixed. The MonoDroid 4.2.6 seems still having the issue.
- My exact problem is this. In the main action I start 5 async service requests. 4 service requests to one service and 1 service request to another service. Before sending the requests I add [ServiceName]Completed event listeners. The event listener for the service with one call is fired and two of the other event listeners are fired but they are fired twice. First time with the .Result equal null and the second time with the valid .Result object. The other two event listeners are never fired. On the service side I correctly receive all 5 requests and the service sends back all the responses.
- It is rather difficult to isolate the problem. Two many things were changed in the environment. The last version that worked was running on the Windows 7, using MonoDroid 4.2.4 and VS2010 was used for compiling the project.
- Now the problem is revealed under Windows 8, using MonoDroid 4.2.6 and VS2012 was used for compiling the project.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like this is a bug pure and simple in the Mono code.

Looking at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7200 it claims this is now available in 6.0.2 in the Beta channel.

If you are still seeing the original problem, then contact Xamarin via Bugzilla - and via support@xamarin.com too if needed - it looks like they are keen to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Mono for Android 4.2.7](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_for_Android_4.2.7), which has a number of related bug fixes.